# How to select grouped data by date column? [ mysql ]

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, union-all

I have 3 tables, `users`, `user_spents`, and `user_incomes`.

- `user_spents` and `user_incomes` tables contains activities of users per date.
- There can be multiple activities in one date per user. (e.g. `user` can have multiple spent or income in 2022-04-01 date).
- It's **not** mandatory that user must have `spent` or `income` in a given date

I want to select activities of **single** user grouped and filtered by date.

Sql Fiddle Link and sql What I have tried so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/846c851/1

What am I doing wrong? Can you give me any suggestions?

Example data what I want to achieve:

```
name    spent   income  date
----------------------------------
Jack    8       12      2022-04-01
Jack    4       56      2022-04-02
Jack    NULL    44      2022-04-03
Jack    7       NULL    2022-04-04
```

Sample data. (Alse included in sql fiddle)

```
Users Table:
id  name
1     Jack

User Spents:
id  user_id spent   date
1     1       2     2022-04-01
2     1       1     2022-04-01
3     1       5     2022-04-01
4     1       3     2022-04-02
5     1       1     2022-04-02

User Spents:
id  user_id income  date
1     1       44        2022-04-03
2     1       15        2022-04-02
3     1       41        2022-04-02
4     1       12        2022-04-01
5     2       54        2022-04-01
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please include a minimal sample of data directly in your question.

Comment: Edited and included sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get all the rows of `user_spents` and `user_incomes` and then join to `users` to aggregate:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       SUM(t.spent) spent,
       SUM(t.income) income, 
       t.date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, spent, null income, date FROM user_spents
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_id, null, income, date FROM user_incomes
) t ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.name = 'Jack' -- remove this condition to get results for all users
GROUP BY u.id, t.date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=191373c7a78b399b8215982817e60008).

Comment: Thank you. It worked . Why `user_id, spent, null income` does not throw error but there is not comma after `null` ?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze  `income` is the alias for this `null` column. It could be written: `null as income`, but `as` is optional.

Comment: If I have `user_id`, Is it more performant if I filter with `user_id` in subQuery? Or Leave outer filter like you have?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze it is always better to filter by the primary key of the table. Also, if the user's name is not unique you might get unexpected results.

Comment: I meant, if it is better to filter in subquery or out of sub query? by the performance viewpoint?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze yes, it is better to filter inside the subquery separately for each of the 2 tables: `SELECT user_id, spent, null income, date FROM user_spents WHERE user_id = 1 UNION ALL SELECT user_id, null, income, date FROM user_incomes WHERE user_id = 1`